# How to alter Sequence in PostgreSQL with specific max(id) from a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get following SQL script syntax right. In postgres, you can't really chain "alter sequence" with "select max(id)". So what's the right way to write script in a way that PostgreSQL accepts it?

Here is the script so you can have an idea what I need:

```
 alter SEQUENCE notification_settings_seq START with (select max(id) from game_user)
```

Comment: Just run this command:

    SELECT setval('my_table_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM my_table));

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This restarts your sequence with new value:

```
do $$
declare maxid int;
begin
    select max(id) from game_user into maxid;
    execute 'alter SEQUENCE seq_name RESTART with '|| maxid;   
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I edited a bit but it does what I need. Apparently, this question has already been answered. My bad for posting duplicates. დიდი მადლობა!

Comment: @Amiko - You're welcome. გაიხარე ))

Comment: SELECT setval('my_table_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM my_table));

Comment: If sequence contains uppercase letters in name: 
SELECT setval(' "Foo" ', 42); 

Notice the double quotes inside the single quotes